# R - Transformations of continuous predictors, using predicted values

Tags: r, regression, lm

In the past, I have been assessing the relationship between outcome and continuous predictors without taking other predictors into account.  I have also been playing around with a way to determine that same relationship when taking other model predictors into account using the predict function…but can’t get my head around a couple of things. Probably not the best example, but I’ve replicated the problem with the IRIS dataset (using Sepal.Length as the outcome variable):

```
library(ggplot2)
irisdata <- iris
```

Here is what I might use to explore the relationship between sepal.length and petal.width; and determine whether a transformation is required (in this case I might just keep as linear).

```
  ggplot(irisdata, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +    
    stat_smooth(method = "loess", color = 'red', size = 1.3, span = 0.5)   +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), size = 1, color = 'magenta', se = FALSE) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = 'purple', se = FALSE)
```

I’m interested in whether that relationship will change when including my other model variables. Here’s the final model excluding petal.width:

```
irismodel <- lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Species, data=irisdata)
summary(irismodel)
irisdata$predictedlength <- predict(irismodel, irisdata, type = "response")
```

And here is what I may use to see if the relationship has changed (in this case, both relationships look similar):

```
  ggplot(irisdata, aes(x=predictedlength, y=Petal.Width)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +    
    stat_smooth(method = "loess", color = 'red', size = 1.3, span = 0.5)   +
    stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), size = 1, color = 'magenta', se = FALSE) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", color = 'purple', se = FALSE)
```

Finally, when I include petal.width in the final model pedal.width is a significant variable:

```
  irismodel2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Species, data= irisdata)
  summary(irismodel2)
```

However, when I include it as a predictor with ‘predictedlength’, it becomes non-significant:

```
  irismodel3 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Width + predictedlength, data= irisdata)
  summary(irismodel3)
```

I guess there are two questions here:

1. Why does petal.width ‘lose’ statistical significance when included in the model with the predictedvalue (ie. model 3)?
2. What is a reasonable approach for determining a correct continuous transformation? When considering transformations, should the impact of other predictors be taken into account? In this example petal.width more or less looks the same but in more complex models I’ve built the transformation requirements have changed (maybe I need to add a degree to a polynomial etc). I guess this is mostly due to a collinearity issue.

Thanks

Output from code below:

summary(irismodel)

```
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        2.39039    0.26227   9.114 5.94e-16 ***
Sepal.Width        0.43222    0.08139   5.310 4.03e-07 ***
Petal.Length       0.77563    0.06425  12.073  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor -0.95581    0.21520  -4.442 1.76e-05 ***
Speciesvirginica  -1.39410    0.28566  -4.880 2.76e-06 ***

Multiple R-squared:  0.8633,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8595
```

summary(irismodel2)

```
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        2.17127    0.27979   7.760 1.43e-12 ***
Petal.Width       -0.31516    0.15120  -2.084  0.03889 *  
Sepal.Width        0.49589    0.08607   5.761 4.87e-08 ***
Petal.Length       0.82924    0.06853  12.101  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesversicolor -0.72356    0.24017  -3.013  0.00306 ** 
Speciesvirginica  -1.02350    0.33373  -3.067  0.00258 ** 

Multiple R-squared:  0.8673,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8627
```

summary(irismodel3)

```
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -0.30055    0.35236  -0.853    0.395    
Petal.Width     -0.07546    0.07406  -1.019    0.310    
predictedlength  1.06692    0.07337  14.541   <2e-16 ***

Multiple R-squared:  0.8643,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8624
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to your first question

> Why does petal.width ‘lose’ statistical significance when included in
>   the model with the predictedvalue (ie. model 2)?

I presume that you meant "model 3". Predicted value is obtained via linear regression in model 1, and from the results, this regression has a $R^2$ of 0.8633. This means that the model explains 86.33% of the variance in the data. When you put it as a predictor in model 3, you're in fact using the fitted model1 to fit the data. Naturally, model 1 has a huge explanatory power over petal.width.

Note: You should only use *independent variables* as predictors.

Regarding question 2, your choice of transformations should be grounded in theory. The rationale for fitting a model on the data through regression is usually to find a model that can explain some phenomenon, hence we will often opt for a simpler model.

Suppose your model finds that length^2 is a good fit, it might be because there is a relationship between your dependent variable and the area (length^2). However, length^7, even if it is a good fit, is not intuitive in anyway. You also have to be wary of *overfitting* to your data. Overfitting occurs when your model explains so much of the data that it included too much noises (random fluctuations, errors) in your model, such that it cannot be generalised and used for data beyond your model. A higher $r^2$ may not always means that your model is the best.

See [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) and bias-variance trade-off for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the 1st question might be the correlation between predicted.value and petal.width. They might be highly correlated which can lead to variance inflation and that might reduce the significance of petal.width when you are including both of them for building the model.